# visual basic loop image with picture box and timer

Tags: vba, timer, picturebox

This is done in Visual Basic, using picture box and timer. I'm trying to get an image to float up, exiting the form then coming back from the bottom then going back up again, looping again . So far when i load it, the form only shows the image going up and then it disappears and doesn't come back. I don't know what to do during the Else part

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick, MyBase.Load
   If PictureBox1.Top < Me.Height Then
    PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 10
   Else
    PictureBox1 = 0
   End If
    Timer1.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing your conditions is always going to be True. Since you are checking if your PictureBox1.Top value is lower than Me.Height, and if it is, you are reducing said value even more.

You should change If to :

```
If PictureBox1.Top > Me.Height Then
   PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 10
```

Note that, since the coordinates used in visual basics have it's origin (x = 0, y = 0) on the top left of the screen, the higher you go, the lower your .top value is, and as such you will reach the top of your screen only when your .top reach 0.

You should also change your else to :

```
Else
    PictureBox1.Top = 0
```

And it should work.